# Odd reputation increments?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

Just today, the upvotes I've been getting make my total go up by a seemingly random amount from 6 to 10. I thought all upvotes were supposed to give 10, right? I'm absolutely sure (by looking at the counts) that I haven't been downvoted on those questions and sometimes they're in odd increments like 7, or sometimes they appear as 0 but change later. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Which site is this happening on?

Comment: StackOverflow...

Comment: Where are you seeing these numbers? Can you screenshot these numbers?

Comment: @random: By hovering over my username... +4, +17, 0, +8...

Comment: But when I look at my Reputation tab the numbers are right. Possibly since I used the "recalculate reputation" button since then? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to the reputation cap!  When you get over 200 points of reputation, the exact points you get for each additional vote depends on how much room you have left (cap of 200 + accepted answers).  In this situation, you best bet is to try to get some answers accepted before the day rolls over!

For example, let's say you've earned 198 points during the day and have no accepted answers.  Then you get another upvote.  That would normally give you ten points but instead you get two points.  Shortly thereafter, you get an accepted answer.  Now your total for the day jumps up to 215.  Then you get a downvote, etc.  It can get really confusing but it is all due to the reputation cap.

---

**Edit:** Important note for anyone carefully examining the reputation tab and trying to apply the reputation cap rules to a given day in which a user exceeded the reputation cap:

- the reputation cap rules may appear to be violated **if a reputation recalc has not been requested since that date for that user**.

In other words, the total reputation that the page is trying to display for that date was calculated as it happened.  The data that is being displayed, upvotes, accepted answers, etc. is as of the time you are viewing the page.  **These are two different inputs to the reputation cap algorithm.**

For example, a deleted answer will still show up in the score for that day, but will not appear in the line items.  The page will make the line items sum to the total no matter what, even at the expense of the rep cap rules.  This may create strange partial credit upvotes that don't seem to make sense.  Trust that the score made sense when it was happening.  A [reputation recalc](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) will sort out these discrepancies.

Comment: "The exact points you get for each additional vote depend on how many accepted answers you have." -- I'm not sure what you mean by that, but no. When you hit the cap, you can still get 15 from accepts, but you get 0 for upvotes. The rep/vote doesn't somehow vary based on your total number of accepts

Comment: I just clarified with an example.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now! Thanks! @Michael Mrozek: But I kept getting reputation afterwards...

Comment: @minitech: The algorithm must have been messy to write.  If you look in activity it does strange things like count a partial vote in the middle of a series of votes.  But the vote that gets penalized is arbitrary; what counts is the total score and the total is correct.

Comment: That's not exactly how the rep cap works... the rep cap only counts upvotes and downvotes to 200 in chronological order; accepts and bounties are immune from it. The effect is the same as how you've described, but the implementation is how I've described it.

Comment: @waiwai933: You are completely correct about the rule itself but the activity tab does not always reflect the chronological nature of the rule.  I looked at my own activity tab and that of several high rep users and found several instances of non-chronological partial credit.