# 200 limit wasn't calculated correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, voting-limits

Below is the snapshot of what I can see now on my reputation tab.
However, I think that numbers are a little off.

There is a limit 200 a day. I definitely hit the limit. I can tell that by those few upvotes that where not accounted. You can see one recent upvote like this in the list.

I have 6 correct answers, which is 6x15 = 90.

So I expect the total to be 290. I can understand -1 from downvote. So result would be 289, not 279.

Can anybody explain why? Not a big deal, just curious if this is a bug or I miss something.

[image]

Comment: There's also a -2 from another downvote, so it'd be 287?

Comment: @Anna Lear - and there is compensating +2 too from upvote that was supposed to be +10, but was cut off by the 200 limit.

Comment: Aha, my bad. Missed that.

Comment: Read this answer and then perform a reputation recalc and check the numbers again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92324/odd-reputation-increments/92327#92327

Comment: @Rick Sladkey - thank you, recalculation fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened previously because of reputation skew from deleted posts and votes not immediately being accounted for.  [This is no longer the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).